# Can I use python return function to only return the value to the specific function

Tags: python, function, return

If I have this

```
def fun1:
    a = 2
    b = 3
    return a
    return b     #problem is here
def fun2:
    c = fun1()
print(fun1())
```

I want to `return a` be a default return and fun1 return a to every other functions but `return b` only works for returning to fun2 and nowhere else

Comment: basically I want c in fun2 be equal to 3 and print in main, prints 2

Comment: It sounds like you want two different functions. (btw what you have posted is not python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is create an optional parameter for the function which decides what value to return.

```py
def fun1(arg=0):
    a = 2
    if arg != 0:
        a = 3
    return a
def fun2():
    c = fun1(1)
print(fun1())
fun2()
```

Here if you call fun1() without any arguments, it will return you 2. But if you give it any integer argument [ example: fun1(2) or fun1(1) ], it will return you 3.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever `return a` is executed - it EXITS the function `fun1`.

So the line `return b` will NEVER be executed.

You can do something like:

```py
def fun1(return_b=False):
    a = 2
    b = 3
    if return_b:
        return b
    else:
        return a

def fun2:
    c = fun1(return_b=True)
```

Read more about Default Argument Values [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values).

If you want to return both `a` and `b`, you can return a tuple of them: `return a, b`

Answer (score 0):

A function can only return one output at a time. Meaning if you have more than one `return` statements in the quesiton, only the first one would be executed and any line written after that statement won't be executed.

In your example you typed `return a` before `return b` meaning the function would only return the value of a and the `return b` line won't be executed.

From your comment on your own question I can see that you want to print `a` first and then want the value of `c` to be 3. For that you can do this -

```
def fun1():
    a = 2
    b = 3
    print(a)
    return b

def fun2():
    c = fun1()

fun1()
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need two different functions.

Everyone just calls `fun1()`, but only `fun2()` calls `fun1a()`:

```py
def fun1():
    a = 2
    b = 3
    return a

def fun1a():
    a = 2
    b = 3
    return b 

def fun2():
    c = fun1a()
    return c
print(fun1())
print(fun2())
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is only an answer to your strange idea: first, get the current frame through [`inspect.currentframe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.currentframe), and then get the frame called by the previous layer through the current frame and [`inspect.getframeinfo`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getframeinfo). The function name will be recorded in the returned value, and different values can be returned by comparing the function name.

```
import inspect


def fun1():
    a = 2
    b = 3
    curr_frame = inspect.currentframe()
    back_frameinfo = inspect.getframeinfo(curr_frame.f_back)
    return b if back_frameinfo.function == 'fun2' else a


def fun2():
    return fun1()


print(fun1(), fun2())    # 2 3
```